# satellizer json web token not being generated properly

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jwt, satellizer, json-web-token

I have integrated https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth with my laravel application. The token is being generated but when the following lines are added, they don't get generated properly and console.log() returns - token is not defined

```
$customClaims = [
        'sub' => $user->id,
        'iat' => time(),
        'exp' => time() + (2 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60)
    ];

 $payload = app('tymon.jwt.payload.factory')->make($customClaims);
```

Answer (score 0):

How to create a Token based on anything you like

```
use JWTFactory;

$customClaims = ['foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'bob'];

$payload = JWTFactory::make($customClaims);

$token = JWTAuth::encode($payload);
```

You can now return this token

You can also chain claims..

```
// add a custom claim with a key of `foo` and a value of ['bar' => 'baz']
$payload = JWTFactory::sub(123)->aud('foo')->foo(['bar' => 'baz'])->make();

$token = JWTAuth::encode($payload);
```

Can try this instead of `app('tymon.jwt.payload.factory')->make($customClaims);`

Comment: The first method still gives [object Object] in console

Comment: does the object contain a key called `token`?